# Fitness too low error when trying to run tezos-activate-alpha. on another terminal

Tags: alphanet

I'm trying to run  tezos-activate-alpha on another terminal against my sandbox but get this error: Fitness too low.

Answer (score 2):

This error usually means that protocol alpha is already activated.